# Encrypting and decrypting a folder

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography

I am developing an application that'll decrypt encrypted files when a user successfully logs in. From what I understand, OpenSSL does not have a built-in function for this. So what I plan to do is zip up a folder and encrypt the zip file when I want to encrypt the directory and the reverse when I want to decrypt it. I will use the aes-256-cbc algorithm. The problem is, a user could change their password in my application, so the new password will generate different key and IV pair meaning that I can't decrypt the folder. Does anyone have any suggestions? Login credentials are verified on the server and encrypted zip files are located on the computer running the client application.

Comment: Decrypt it using the old password, and then encrypt it using the new password. (For security reasons, users should enter the old password when changing it.)

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE and when the user forgets his password, then he's done for

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, a user could change their password in my application, so the new password will generate different key and IV pair meaning that I can't decrypt the folder.

The practice is not to use the user credentials to encrypt the data. If the user forgets his credentials, the user is done for.

> Login credentials are verified on the server and encrypted zip files are located on the computer

That's actually giving you an option. If you don't want to store the encryption key on the client side, the server could send the key back as a part of the response and the client application could use it to decrypt or encrypt the data.